# Wordpress Multisite, site em diretório distinto

Tags: php, wordpress, htaccess, plugin-wordpress

tenho uma dúvida, no multisite do Wordpress eu quero saber se tem como eu criar um site em diretório distinto.

por exemplo o site principal é em:

> wordpress.omegainc.com.br

e o site secundário quero que fique em

> omegainc.com.br/teste/blog

isso é possível?

tentei o plugin mapping domain mas não consegui obter exite, pelo oque percebi ele faz o contrario, quando acessado o subsite ele direciona para o domínio que vc quer, pelo menos isso que percebi.

Comment: Um pouco estranha essa configuração... Dúvida: seu MS está configurado com diretórios? Se não me engano, o Domain Mapping permite adicionar mais de um site/domínio sendo que só um é o primário

Comment: esta para subdominios

Comment: Não cheguei a conferir, mas pode ser interessante: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bwordpress%5D+%5B.htaccess%5D+subdomain+directory+multisite

Answer (score 0):

Se sua instalação principal está em omegainc.com.br você pode criar as páginas que quiser em /teste/blog e personalizar como preferir. Assim a função multisite fica apenas para seu subdomínio wordpress.
Agora caso queira 3 coisas totalmente independentes de temas, plugins e configuração teria que usar instalações diferentes para a raiz, subdomínio e diretório. Dessa forma fica mais semântico, é importante considerar.